# Bind Model on Render Yii

Tags: php, yii, model, render, model-binding

I have a CGridView on my view and it works fine. How ever, I need to bind a model variable so that my Advance Search function will be included. My current setup gives an error of Undefined variable: arrayDataProvider.

index.php (View)

```
$this->renderPartial('search',array(
'model'=>$model,
)); 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'LastName',
        'type' => 'raw',
                        'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["LastName"])',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'FirstName',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["FirstName"])',
    ),

            array(
        'name' => 'Email',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["Email"])',
    ),
),
));
```

Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $model=new TblAccountdetails('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        $data = new TblAccountdetails();
        $rawData = $data->getAllData();
        $arrayDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
                'keyField'=>'AID',
                'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>10,
                ),
        ));
        $params =array(
                'arrayDataProvider'=>$arrayDataProvider,
        );

        $this->render('index',array(
                'model'         =>$model,
                'dataProvider'  =>$params,
        ));
}
```

Comment: will you show the undefined index notice error text here in order to identify the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your `$arrayDataProvider` in array `$params` and then pass it in view like `$dataProvider` variable:

```
$params =array(
   'arrayDataProvider'=>$arrayDataProvider,
);
...
$this->render('index',array(
     'model'         =>$model,
     'dataProvider'  =>$params,
));
```

Then in View you should get this variable from array `$dataProvider`:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider['arrayDataProvider'],
   ...
```